# VS Code does not stop at any breakpoints on mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, g++, vscode-debugger

I am trying to test the debugger in VS Code and I believe I have configured my launch.json and tasks.json correctly but the debugger is just not stopping at my breakpoints.

I tried re-installing VS code, re-configuring, trying different source files.. but I just can't get this debugger to run. I am a beginner so most likely something I'm missing.

[image]

I expect the debugger to stop at line 8.

writtenassignment.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    int array [9] = {-10, -7, -1, 0, 4, 7, 8, 12, 19};
    int i, j, sum = 4;
    for (i = 0; i <= 8; i++){
        for (j = i + 1; j <= 8; j++){
                int a = array[i];
                int b = array[j];
                cout << "a: " << a << " b: " << b << " i: " << i << " j: " << j << endl;
            if (a + b == sum) {
                cout << a << " + " << b << " = " << sum << endl;
                //exit;
            }   
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

tasks.json

```
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

launch.json

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(lldb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/writtenassignment",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Compiling with just "g++ writtenassignment.cpp". Also, added the source code to the post!

Comment: Hmm I cannot replicate, the breakpoints work on my env. What is your VS Code version and how are you running the code? Are you running it from the Debug panel?

Comment: VS Code version is 1.39.2. I have tried running it from the Debug panel and also just going to Start > Start Debugging. It just runs right past my breakpoints.

Comment: Try to use GDB and see if you have problem again. That's the best compiler ever!

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, the only time the breakpoints don't work or don't get triggered is if you did not add the `-g` compiler flag when you built the executable.

I noticed from your *launch.json* that you don't call the build task set in *task.json*. Normally, you specify a `preLaunchTask` in your launch configuration, that calls the build task from *task.json* to rebuild the executable, before running it.

What I think happened, was that the **writtenassignment** was already compiled before **without `-g`**, and then when you are launching it again, it's not getting rebuilt with `-g`.

Try with this:

*tasks.json*

```
{
    "type": "shell",
    "label": "build-writtenassignment",
    "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
    "args": [
        "-g",
        "${workspaceFolder}/writtenassignment.cpp",
        "-o",
        "${workspaceFolder}/writtenassignment"
    ],
    "options": {
        "cwd": "/usr/bin"
    },
    "problemMatcher": [
        "$gcc"
    ],
    "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
    }
}
```

*launch.json*

```
{
    "name": "run-writtenassignment",
    "type": "cppdbg",
    "request": "launch",
    "preLaunchTask": "build-writtenassignment",  // <-------------- ADDED!
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/writtenassignment",
    "args": [],
    "stopAtEntry": true,
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "environment": [],
    "externalConsole": false,
    "MIMode": "lldb"
}
```

I added a `preLaunchTask` to call the build task in *tasks.json* (I renamed each config to make it easier to reference). I also explicitly specified the file *writtenassignment.cpp* and the output **writtenassignment** instead of `${file}`. Then just run it from the Debug panel.

[image]

Comment: Hmm I deleted all of my files and just copied everything you have and it just doesn't seem to want to stop at my breakpoint. It goes through and just outputs to the debug console.

Comment: Question - are you on macOS Catalina? I'm starting to wonder if the new update broke my VS Code.

Comment: @AdrianDavid No, I am still on High Sierra and I don't have access to a Catalina machine, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I found this issue is either related to the recent update of Xcode or an issue with Xcode and Catalina macOS update.

I have downloaded Xcode version 10.3, added the miDebuggerPath in the launch.json, and now my debugger stops at breakpoints as expected.

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/3829 for additional details.

launch.json

```
{
    "name": "run-writtenassignment",
    "type": "cppdbg",
    "request": "launch",
    "preLaunchTask": "build-writtenassignment",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/writtenassignment",
    "args": [],
    "stopAtEntry": true,
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "environment": [],
    "externalConsole": false,
    "MIMode": "lldb",
    "miDebuggerPath": "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/lldb-mi" // <-------------- ADDED!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me while debugging just one file was:

```
task.json:
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "gcc build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.o"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        }
    ]
}
```

launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gcc",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "gcc build active file",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.o",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
            "additionalSOLibSearchPath": "."
        }
    ]
}
```

Note I added ".o" after "${fileBasenameNoExtension}".
Next, make sure the c/cpp file is opened and in the active tab.
Now you can start debugging.